# Change Isotope's element animation

Tags: javascript, html, css, jquery-isotope

### Explanation

I'm trying to change the animation from this [Isotope](https://isotope.metafizzy.co/)'s "load more" button, but I've gone through every code and still can't figure out how to do it. As you can see in the first gif below, the "new" items acts like they were stacked and then go to their desired positions. I'm trying to achieve something like the second gif, where the items just fade in in their positions.

**first gif**

[image]

**second gif**

[image]

### Code

You can also see it in [this JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/fwme8ykq/).

```js
// external js: isotope.pkgd.js
$(document).ready(function() {

  // init Isotope
  var $container = $('.isotope').isotope({
    itemSelector: '.element-item',
    layoutMode: 'fitRows'
  });

  // bind filter button click
  $('#filters').on('click', 'button', function() {
    var filterValue = $(this).attr('data-filter');
    $container.isotope({
      filter: filterValue
    });
  });

  // change is-checked class on buttons
  $('.button-group').each(function(i, buttonGroup) {
    var $buttonGroup = $(buttonGroup);
    $buttonGroup.on('click', 'button', function() {
      $buttonGroup.find('.is-checked').removeClass('is-checked');
      $(this).addClass('is-checked');
    });
  });

  //****************************
  // Isotope Load more button
  //****************************
  var initShow = 8; //number of items loaded on init & onclick load more button
  var counter = initShow; //counter for load more button
  var iso = $container.data('isotope'); // get Isotope instance

  loadMore(initShow); //execute function onload

  function loadMore(toShow) {
    $container.find(".hidden").removeClass("hidden");

    var hiddenElems = iso.filteredItems.slice(toShow, iso.filteredItems.length).map(function(item) {
      return item.element;
    });
    $(hiddenElems).addClass('hidden');
    $container.isotope('layout');

    //when no more to load, hide show more button
    if (hiddenElems.length == 0) {
      jQuery("#load-more").hide();
    } else {
      jQuery("#load-more").show();
    };
  }

  //when load more button clicked
  $("#load-more").click(function() {
    if ($('#filters').data('clicked')) {
      //when filter button clicked, set initial value for counter
      counter = initShow;
      $('#filters').data('clicked', false);
    } else {
      counter = counter;
    };

    counter = counter + initShow;

    loadMore(counter);
  });

  //when filter button clicked
  $("#filters").click(function() {
    $(this).data('clicked', true);

    loadMore(initShow);
  });

});
```

```css
* {
  -webkit-box-sizing: border-box;
  -moz-box-sizing: border-box;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

body {
  font-family: sans-serif;
}

.hidden {
  visibility: hidden;
  width: 0px !important;
  height: 0px !important;
  margin: 0px !important;
  padding: 0px !important;
}


/* ---- isotope ---- */

.isotope {
  border: 1px solid #333;
}


/* ---- .element-item ---- */

.element-item {
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
  margin: 5px;
  padding: 10px;
}

.element-item.item-1 {
  background: #e03a3e;
}

.element-item.item-2 {
  background: #f5821f;
}

.element-item.item-3 {
  background: #fdb827;
}

.element-item.item-4 {
  background: #61bb46;
}

.element-item.item-5 {
  background: #2c73d2;
}

.element-item.item-6 {
  background: #933196;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://unpkg.com/isotope-layout@3/dist/isotope.pkgd.js"></script>
<h1>Isotope - Load more button</h1>

<div id="filters" class="button-group">
  <button class="button is-checked" data-filter="*">show all</button>
  <button class="button" data-filter=".item-1">item-1</button>
  <button class="button" data-filter=".item-2">item-2</button>
  <button class="button" data-filter=".item-3">item-3</button>
  <button class="button" data-filter=".item-4">item-4</button>
  <button class="button" data-filter=".item-5">item-5</button>
  <button class="button" data-filter=".item-6">item-6</button>
</div>

<div class="isotope">
  <div class="element-item item-5" data-category="item-5">5</div>
  <div class="element-item item-1" data-category="item-1">1</div>
  <div class="element-item item-5" data-category="item-5">5</div>
  <div class="element-item item-4" data-category="item-4">4</div>
  <div class="element-item item-4" data-category="item-4">4</div>
  <div class="element-item item-2" data-category="item-2">2</div>
  <div class="element-item item-5" data-category="item-5">5</div>
  <div class="element-item item-1" data-category="item-1">1</div>
  <div class="element-item item-4" data-category="item-4">4</div>
  <div class="element-item item-3" data-category="item-3">3</div>
  <div class="element-item item-4" data-category="item-4">4</div>
  <div class="element-item item-3" data-category="item-3">3</div>
  <div class="element-item item-4" data-category="item-4">4</div>
  <div class="element-item item-1" data-category="item-1">1</div>
  <div class="element-item item-5" data-category="item-5">5</div>
  <div class="element-item item-5" data-category="item-5">5</div>
  <div class="element-item item-3" data-category="item-3">3</div>
  <div class="element-item item-3" data-category="item-3">3</div>
  <div class="element-item item-3" data-category="item-3">3</div>
  <div class="element-item item-2" data-category="item-2">2</div>
  <div class="element-item item-6" data-category="item-6">6</div>
  <div class="element-item item-5" data-category="item-5">5</div>
  <div class="element-item item-3" data-category="item-3">3</div>
  <div class="element-item item-2" data-category="item-2">2</div>
  <div class="element-item item-6" data-category="item-6">6</div>
  <div class="element-item item-3" data-category="item-3">3</div>
  <div class="element-item item-5" data-category="item-5">5</div>
  <div class="element-item item-3" data-category="item-3">3</div>
  <div class="element-item item-6" data-category="item-6">6</div>
  <div class="element-item item-1" data-category="item-1">1</div>
  <div class="element-item item-4" data-category="item-4">4</div>
  <div class="element-item item-2" data-category="item-2">2</div>
  <div class="element-item item-3" data-category="item-3">3</div>
  <div class="element-item item-1" data-category="item-1">1</div>
</div>

<button id="load-more">Load more</button>
```

Thanks in advance,
Luiz.

Comment: What do you want to achieve? Do you want to change the animation? Do you have the code for second gif?

Comment: Yes, I'd like to change the animation to something like the second gif. You can see it's code in [this JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/z9dpr6mh/), but it's different to the "load more" button, it only uses [Isotope's insert](https://isotope.metafizzy.co/methods.html#insert) to add new items, instead of items already in the code.